# Navigation Drawer : current navigation fragment not updated when back to the activity

Tags: android

I have a drawer navigation activity with 3 destinations. This activity immediatly launches another activity. When back to the drawer activity, we are on the first destination, but the corresponding fragment is not updated, onStart is not triggered. The fragment seems to be restored in its original state. I have to click on the first item of the menu to force the display of an updated fragment (I can see that onStart is triggered doing this).

I've tried to programmaticaly do this forcing the navigation controller to navigate to the wanted destination (nav_pets), but this doesn't produce the correct result here.

```
        navController.navigate(R.id.nav_empty);
        navController.navigate(R.id.nav_pets);
```

How could I handle this and get an updated fragment when back to the activity ?

Comment: Let us see what you did programmatically, add your code

Comment: I'va added the code

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
----->
//enter code here 
<-------



        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I've put the code in onStart() which is not triggered, so I don't think onCreateView will ?